# Using dusk with phpunit tests causes invalid url error

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I have just installed laravel dusk to try and add some browser testing to my phpunit testing. However I keep getting this error when I run the below in terminal:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Browser
```

The result of this is:

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: 
unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
(Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.77)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 
(4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

This is my driver in `DuskTestCase.php`

```
/**
 * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
 *
 * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
 */
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless'
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `APP_URL` in your `.env[.dusk.local]` file?

Comment: I don't have that file but my `APP_URL` in the `.env` is `http://local.test`

Comment: How are you running Dusk? In a VM like Homestead? Or in combination with `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I am using it with homestead yes

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1` as the value of `APP_URL`.

Comment: So if I drop that into the `RemoteWebDriver`?

Comment: No, change it in your `.env` file.

Comment: But won't that break my homestead?, trying it now!

Comment: Same problem, no change in the error from above

Comment: Are you running the example test without any changes?

Comment: Correct, but rather than check for laravel, I am checking for other text. It doesn't fail, just errors like above

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Browser`. Try `php artisan dusk` instead. Also: What command line are you using? Your host machine's (Mac OS)? Or are you running Dusk in Homestead via SSH?

Comment: Local machine, and I am using `vendor/bin` as this will get triggered when I run the full test suite on CircleCI. `php artisan dusk` works fine as long as my vagrant box is up

Comment: You can use `php artisan dusk` on CircleCI: https://laravel.com/docs/dusk#running-tests-on-circle-ci

Comment: Well I have a homestead VM running, but I run it from the macos terminal in my sites folder with `php artisan dusk` which works, but I can't run all my tests at once with `vendor/bin`

Comment: Yes that command works

Comment: "but I can't run all my tests at once with vendor/bin": Why is that important?

Comment: Because I run my `phpunit` tests with `vendor/bin/phpunit tests/` and the tests folder contains the browser folder so it trys to run them

Comment: Unless there is a way to tell unit to ignore that folder

Comment: When you run `vendor/bin/phpunit` without a directory, PHPUnit will use the the directories specified in `phpunit.xml`: `Feature` and `Unit`

Comment: Okay, I will look in there to exclude that folder, it might just be selecting them all.

Comment: Thanks anyway...